# Mi proyecto funciona en un host pero en otro no funciona php mysql ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

hace poco empece en esto y al subir un proyecto a infinityfree no funcionaba correctamente, saltaban errores de que no existian los ficheros, en ciertos lugares si funcionaba codigo que en otro lado no y en todas las paginas se veia el error de CORB, donde se bloqueaba supuesto contenido de origenes cruzados (todo esta cargado en el mismo dominio). Desactive el ajax para ver si funcionaba con php por lo menos y saltaba error 500. Cambie el codigo lo mas que pude en mi entendimiento.
Hoy probe en otro host por las dudas y funciona todo, pero todo. Ni un error quizas alguno por mi codigo mal optimizado pero funciona todo y no es lento.

infinityFree

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

000webhost

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito un consejo, en principio pense que las diferencias entre host podrian ser de compatibilidades, alguno soporta php otro no por ejemplo. Que necesito leer? que falta instruirme para entender mas estos fundamentos. Estuve leyendo que aplicando headers podia controlar ciertas habilitaciones del servidor, pero no tengo claro donde ingresar ese codigo y los que ingrese por ajax no tuvieron ningun impacto en infinityFree.

Comment: Me parece que este tipo de pregunta debe hacerse al soporte técnico del proveedor del hosting.

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer es ir y ver que estas llamado por Ajax que te da el bloqueo a ver si es algo del Hosting como dice el amigo @Lobos

Comment: @JosueVargas Pero no es Ajax.. ya que probe con php puro y de la misma forma no funciono.. a eso me refiero.. voy a tratar con soporte tecnico como dice lobos. Gracias